# Check which thread is running on which CPU in linux

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, multicore

I'm interested in finding which thread is running on which core/CPU. My Tomcat6 is using a single CPU core 100% and all other CPUs (my server has 16 other cores idle) are not being utilized... so I'm trying to figure out what went wrong.

Comment: you need a profiler .. or at least a bunch of thread dumps to tell you where the load is. most commonly this means you have a single very inefficient method or an infinite loop

Comment: Perhaps include a comment with the downvotes?

Comment: Actually, Welcome to StackOverflow! Please have a look at the FAQ for details on how to use this site. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you @didierc , but I've been using SO for about 3 years. I use this id from my office.

Comment: that's your prerogative to use an unexperienced account. If you've been using SO for so long, you should already know that such a vague question is calling for downvotes.

Comment: May I ask you, why do you think the question is so vague?

Comment: I don't think this question is vague. I was just wondering myself if it is possible to determine on which core a thread is running on - or better - if it is possible to assign a thread to a specific core.

Comment: er... what is the actual question? In case that you just want to know which thread (including name) is using most cpu time then please try threadcpu: http://www.tuxad.com/blog/archives/2018/10/01/threadcpu_-_show_cpu_usage_of_threads/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Funny that people downvotes but don't tell why. I searched for a while and found that following command gives which thread running on which CPU:

```
ps -p <PID> -L -o pid,tid,psr
```

Where < PID > is the pid of the process we are interested in.

Comment: It may give some idea of which thread WAS running on which CPU.  By the time the output appears, never mind the time taken for a human to read it, the result is totally stale.  How many interrupts from disks, network cards etc. etc. will have happened while this command runs?

Comment: Yes, I agree, and that's natural because threads can be scheduled to run on any CPU... I guess.