# Thread affinity in linux

Tags: linux, multithreading, pthreads, affinity

I have made an application in c which creates 4 threads. How can I check which thread is running on which core through terminal and through code.

Comment: Have you tried `pthread_getaffinity_np()` ? http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setaffinity_np.3.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16381138/check-which-thread-is-running-on-which-cpu-in-linux

Comment: Normally, the OS distributes threads to the different CPUs, so any CPU that it's running on right now may or may not be the same CPU it's running on in a millisecond. However, you can control thread affinity with POSIX threads, which Linux supports, or you can use e.g. a tool like `htop` to assign threads/processes to CPUs.

Comment: @SergeiKulik pthread_getaffinity_np() is always returning 0, even though I am setting affinity using pthread_setaffinity_np().

Comment: What does the manpage have to say about that particular returnvalue?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer about how to check it using terminal.
/home# for i in $(pgrep applicationName); do ps -mo pid,tid,fname,user,psr -p $i;done